identified duplicates according to criteria
I have a t1 table with duplicates. I would like to identify these duplicates by putting a flag on them.

I would like labeled all the lines whose idcommande is unique as "keep"
For the same idCommand, we set the one with status = 'in progress' AND typecom = 'canceled' to "keep"
For the same idcommand, we set to keep those which have an idRef, if idRef is not null.

The flag can be of any type True or False or other
CREATE TABLE t1 (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
    idcommande VARCHAR(50),
    date_ DATE,
    typecom VARCHAR(50),
    statut VARCHAR(20),
    idref INT
);

INSERT INTO t1 (idcommande, date_, statut, typecom, idref) VALUES
('1001', '2024-09-15', 'in progress', 'in progress', 1),  -- don't want
('1001', '2024-09-15', 'in progress', 'canceled', 2),     -- keep
('1002', '2024-09-16', 'completed', 'sent', 3),           -- keep
('1003', '2024-09-16', 'completed', 'sent', NULL),         -- don't want           
('1003', '2024-09-17', 'completed', 'sent', 4);           -- keep
('1004', '2024-09-15', 'completed', 'canceled', 5),     -- keep

I tried to do this but I don't really understand how to use partition. The lines with rownum at 1 are kept but the line with idref at null is also kept even though I don't want it
WITH RankedResults AS (
   select *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY t1.idcommande 
           ORDER BY 
               CASE 
                   WHEN t1.statut = 'in progress' and t1.typeCom != 'canceled' THEN 1 
                   WHEN t1.idref IS NULL THEN 1
                   ELSE 0 
               END,
               t1.date_, 
               t1.typecom
       ) AS RowNum
   FROM (
       SELECT *
       FROM t1
    ) as t1
)
 
select * from (SELECT * FROM RankedResults) as tmain

Résult:


Sample data is great, but can you also specify the expected result. I.e. provide a complete [mcve].

Hello, @jarlh sorry the code I put is correct, I got confused. The code does what I want. I'm not deleting the discussion, if there are people who consider that it is easier to do

No problem at all. We are all here to learn.

Salut @dia05!

Check your conditions on the CASE statement:

t1.typecom = 'canceled' (instead of != 'canceled')
idref IS NOT NULL to prioritize rows where idref is present (instead of idref IS NULL).
ELSE 3



WITH RankedResults AS (
  SELECT
    t1.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY t1.idcommande ORDER BY
      CASE
        WHEN t1.statut = 'in progress' AND t1.typecom = 'canceled' THEN 1
        WHEN t1.idref IS NOT NULL THEN 2
        ELSE 3
      END
    ) AS rownum
  FROM t1
)
SELECT
  id, idcommande, date_, typecom, statut, idref, RowNum,
  CASE
    WHEN cnt = 1 THEN 'keep'
    WHEN RowNum = 1 THEN 'keep'
    ELSE 'do not keep'
  END AS flag
FROM RankedResults
ORDER BY idcommande, RowNum

Output:



id
idcommande
date_
typecom
statut
idref
rownum
flag




2
1001
2024-09-15
canceled
in progress
2
1
keep


1
1001
2024-09-15
in progress
in progress
1
2
do not keep


3
1002
2024-09-16
sent
completed
3
1
keep


4
1002
2024-09-16
sent
completed
NULL
2
do not keeo


5
1003
2024-09-17
sent
completed
4
1
keep




hope this would help
I would suggest checking the case statement the typeCom should by ='cancel' instead of != :

WHEN t1.statut = 'in progress' and t1.typeCom != 'canceled'THEN 1
WHEN t1.idref IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0

I think this query should help you:
I separated each criteria on its own condition then prioritize the data on the order by statement


SELECT idcommande, date_, statut, typecom, idref,case when RN=1 then 'keep' else 'remove'END Keep
 FROM (
SELECT *
,Row_number() Over (Partition by idcommande
  order by idcommande,iif(statut='in progress',1,2),iif(typecom='canceled',1,2),iif(idref is not null,1,2)) RN 
FROM t1
)A



Output:
enter image description here

Hello, iif doesn't exist in posgrsql system, so i replace it by case when ... then ... else ... end, i got the same result.

If you could add the output as text, it would be much better.
